# Feasibility of implementing a Decentralized Identity Management System? (DIDs and VCs)

Tags: blockchain, dapps, decentralization, identity

I am currently working on a project focused on creating a Decentralized Identity Management System by using DIDs and VCs. Our goal is to enable users to have self-sovereign control over their identities and the verification of credentials while ensuring security and privacy.

I am quite new to the blockchain community and working with smart contracts, so I do not know the technical limitations regarding this project.

**Technical Feasibility** Are there any potential technical challenges or limitations in implementing a DICMS on Ethereum that I should be aware of?

**Smart Contracts**: What are the best practices for creating and managing smart contracts to handle identity verification and credential issuance?

**Security and Privacy**: Are there any limitations and implications when it comes to privacy control and security?

**IPFS and Data Integrity**: What are the recommended practices for using IPFS to maintain data integrity in a decentralized system?

**Resources**: Are there any relevant resources, tutorials, or projects we should reference or collaborate with to make this endeavor more successful?

Any other suggestions and an answer to any of the above questions is greatly appreciated!!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a concern for Security and Privacy, especialy the Personal Information.
In many countries and regions, it will be required to control individual Personal Informations.
And it often includes capability to DELETE the information.

But Ethereum's mechanism is not suitable for DELETE capability.
Because of what worte in a blockchain is never deleted.
If you prepare function to clear information and use it, it is not deleting but overwriting to nothing.
So, if attackers track all histories of blockchain, they can know the Personal Information.
As a result, it may be a violation to protecte Personal Information requirements.

The Ethereum's mechanism has tough security, if data is able to be opend to all around the world.
But it has not enough, if data must be closed.

On the other hand, if you make Ethereum's network as closed network, you lose a concept 'Decentralized'.
Because there is an administrator who decides range of closed, yes you are.

I think, it is very hard work to protect Personal Informations with decentralized mechanism.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you!